# is there any way to compare 2 array ID using reduce Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Supposed i have two array

```
// item01
[
    { value: "0", value: "01", display: "Jamsheer", key: "jam" },
    { value: "1", value: "02",  display: "Muhammed", key: "muh" },
    { value: "2", value: "03", display: "Ravi", key: "rav" },
    { value: "3", value: "04", display: "Ajmal", key: "ajm" },
    { value: "4", value: "05",  display: "Ryan", key: "rya" }
]

// item02
[
    { value: "0", value: "01", display: "Kamal" },
    { value: "1", value: "02", display: "Jamal"},
]
```

The final result I need is the difference between these arrays using `id` & `value` and show `item02: display, ID` & `item01: key` – the final result should be like this:

```
[
    { value: "0", value: "01", display: "Kamal",  key: "jam"},
    { value: "1", value: "02", display: "Jamal", key: "muh"},
]
```

i tried `filter` with `some` method but it didn't solved my problem. Is it possible to do something like this using reduce in JavaScript?

Comment: *"i tried filter with some method but it didn't solved my problem. "* Post the JavaScript see [mcve].

Comment: Btw objects cannot contain the same key `value` twice

Answer (score 3):

*Notice that you have arrays with objects that have `value` properties repeated*

- I have modified first `value`s to `id`

I think that what you want is something like this:

```js
// item01
const item01 = [
  { id: "0", value: "01", display: "Jamsheer", key: "jam" },
  { id: "1", value: "02",  display: "Muhammed", key: "muh" },
  { id: "2", value: "03", display: "Ravi", key: "rav" },
  { id: "3", value: "04", display: "Ajmal", key: "ajm" },
  { id: "4", value: "05",  display: "Ryan", key: "rya" }
]

// item02
const item02 = [
  { id: "0", value: "01", display: "Kamal" },
  { id: "1", value: "02", display: "Jamal"},
]

const item01Hash = item01.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[`${c.id}${c.value}`] = c
  return a
}, {})

const result = item02.reduce((a, c) => {
  const { key } = item01Hash[`${c.id}${c.value}`]
  return key
    ? [...a, { ...c, key }]
    : a
}, [])

console.log(result)
```